# Duplicity on a ReadyNAS

Tags: backup, duplicity, readynas

Has anyone here run Duplicity on a ReadyNAS? I'm trying but here's what I get:

```
duplicity full --encrypt-key="ABC123" /home/jason/ scp://jswett@192.168.140.2//gob
Invalid SSH password
Running 'sftp  -oServerAliveInterval=15 -oServerAliveCountMax=2 jswett@192.168.140.2' failed (attempt #1)
```

I've also found [this post](https://bugs.launchpad.net/duplicity/+bug/411145) that says the "Invalid SSH password" message doesn't actually mean invalid SSH password. This would make sense because I'm not using an SSH password; I'm using a public key.

I can `ssh`, `ftp`, `sftp` and `rsync` into my ReadyNAS just fine. (Actually, to be more accurate, I can get past authentication with `ssh`, `ftp` and `sftp` but I can't actually do anything past that. Regardless, that's enough to tell me that "Invalid SSH password" is bogus. `Rsync` works with no problems.)

The post I found says the command will work as soon as the directory at the end of your `scp` command exists, but I don't know how to check for that. I know the share `gob` exists on my ReadyNAS and I know it's writable because I'm writing to it with `rsync`.

Also, here is the verbose output:

```
Using archive dir: /home/jason/.cache/duplicity/3bdd353b29468311ffa8485160da6873
Using backup name: 3bdd353b29468311ffa8485160da6873
Import of duplicity.backends.rsyncbackend Succeeded
Import of duplicity.backends.sshbackend Succeeded
Import of duplicity.backends.localbackend Succeeded
Import of duplicity.backends.botobackend Succeeded
Import of duplicity.backends.cloudfilesbackend Succeeded
Import of duplicity.backends.giobackend Succeeded
Import of duplicity.backends.hsibackend Succeeded
Import of duplicity.backends.imapbackend Succeeded
Import of duplicity.backends.ftpbackend Succeeded
Import of duplicity.backends.webdavbackend Succeeded
Import of duplicity.backends.tahoebackend Succeeded
Main action: full
================================================================================
duplicity 0.6.10 (September 19, 2010)
Args: /usr/bin/duplicity full --encrypt-key=ABC123 -v9 /home/jason/ scp://jswett@192.168.140.2//gob
Linux gob 2.6.35-22-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Sun Sep 19 20:34:50 UTC 2010 i686
/usr/bin/python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 15 2010, 15:52:39)
[GCC 4.4.5]
================================================================================
Using temporary directory /tmp/duplicity-cridGi-tempdir
Registering (mkstemp) temporary file /tmp/duplicity-cridGi-tempdir/mkstemp-ztuF5P-1
Temp has 86334349312 available, backup will use approx 34078720.
Running 'sftp  -oServerAliveInterval=15 -oServerAliveCountMax=2 jswett@192.168.140.2' (attempt #1)
State = sftp, Before = 'jswett@192.168.140.2's'
State = sftp, Before = ''
Invalid SSH password
Running 'sftp  -oServerAliveInterval=15 -oServerAliveCountMax=2 jswett@192.168.140.2' failed (attempt #1)
```

Any ideas as to what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. Are you running this directly from the command line, or from a cron job?  If the latter, perhaps it can't unlock the ssh key, if the key has a passphrase?
2. Have a look in `/var/log/auth.log` or similar on the NAS, to see if it has a message about why the connection is failing.

Comment: Directly from the command line. I'll have a look at that file. Thanks.